# passport authentication not working in my Laravel 5.4 application?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I have configured passport authentication for my model 'Member'(members table).Access token created perfectly while login.But i could not authenticate after login apis.
i am getting below error

```
BadMethodCallException.Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getAuthIdentifierName()
```

Answer (score 0):

i thing you forgot to put auth:api middleware in routes.

Comment: No ...i have given auth:api
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    //return $request->user();
});

Comment: can you explain how you acquire the Bearer access_token and how you access route /user?

Answer (score 0):

please use authentication middleware like

```
Route::group(array('middleware' => ['auth:api']), function() {
   //your routes;
});
```

Comment: @SandeepNambiar run this command `php artisan migrate` and make sure your table in a database.
then add this line in your **User.php** file

`protected $primaryKey = 'your_primary_key';`

Answer (score 0):

Passport by default uses User model and here you are using Member table. Just check if you have included Model class inside the auth.php file inside config folder.

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Member::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

Or try this  https://github.com/santigarcor/laratrust/issues/134#issuecomment-300318982